# Hover in Chrome is not working properly if there's an embed/iframe code on the page

Tags: css, google-chrome, iframe, webkit, hover

I know this is a bit weird but hover in Chrome is not working properly if I have an embed/iframe code on my page.

The problem is that when I mouse out on the top two boxes (li), they would have a ghost hover (meaning, has a hover effect even if my mouse is no longer hovering). This only happens if there's an iframe on the page. I tried removing the iframe (for YouTube embed code) and the problem disappears.

Is there any connection? This is my hover code:

CSS:

```
.boxes > li {
   background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
   border-image: none;
   border-style: none none dashed;
   border-width: medium medium 1px;
   box-shadow: none;
   display: block;
}

.boxes > li:hover {
   background-color: #E0EDFF;
   border-color: #E0EDFF;
   box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #BBB;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="boxes">
  <li>
    <div class="detail">
        <h4>Some Title</h4>
        <div><p>Some paragraph. <a href="#">Read More »</a></p></div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Where are you placing the embedded code (for your iframe)? Above the ul? Inside?

Comment: It's entirely outside the ul. It's actually on the sidebar. The ul is on the main content part. That's why it's kind of weird why it should affect the hover behavior.

Comment: Check out this fiddle and see if you get the ghost hover. http://jsfiddle.net/nickleaf/tKsyw/1/